# Обновление данных в RecyclerView javarx

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, rxjava

У меня есть RecyclerView и он наполнен данными, как мне сделать так ,что если я получаю новые данные с сервера, я, незаметно для пользователя, оставался на текущем элементе списка и обновляю все старые данные, а не обновлял список заново. Для получения данных я использую javarx и retrofit.

Вот так я получаю данные с сервера:

```
public Observable<List<Event>> getDashBoardEvents() {

            return apiLinks.dashBoard().map(DashBoardWrapper::getEvents);

        }

public void displayDashBoard() {
            showLoading();
    Disposable getSubscription = getDashBoardEvents()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(this::onEventGetSuccess, this::onEventGetFailed);
```

Comment: насколько мне помнится методы адаптера `notifyItemChanged()`, `notifyItemRangeChanged()` не изменяют позицию в списке при обновлении. Вычислить, где требуются изменения удобно [утилитой DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html)

Comment: @pavlofff я обновляю данные полностью очищая список и внося новые данные:
 `this.events.clear();`
        `this.events.addAll(events);`
`        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` . Поэтому у меня лист обновляется полностью. Это можно как-то реализовать через обсервабл?

Comment: Нужно чтобы стабильные были itemId